# How to change height and width of each page of a pdf

Tags: pdf

I was wondering how to change width and height of each page of a pdf?

In my scanned pdf, each page has paper size too big, 31.98 × 49.20 inch. I would like to shrink the width and height to smaller ones which are normally seen in pdf files.

Are there some applications or programming tools to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try ghostscript (all one line):

`gs -sOutputFile=output.pdf -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -f input.pdf`

Change `a4` to `letter` for North America.

Comment: (I fixed an earlier, worse answer.)

Comment: Thanks! It reduces the width and height. But why the storage size increases almost three times from 7.4M to 22M?

Comment: It converts it to PostScript and back, but why that should increase file size so dramatically, I don't know. You probably also go from PDF version 1.5+ to 1.4, which may have something to do with it.

Comment: Ghostscript may have to rasterize stuff PS does not support. For simple PDFs, this works nicely. Still looking for a solution that is PDF-only.