# Rescale a PDF file

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdftk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change height and width of each page of a pdf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18294/how-to-change-height-and-width-of-each-page-of-a-pdf)

Is it possible to rescale a PDF file (retaining perspective) to be within a maximum width / height?

Rendering to an image and resizing is not an option – the output PDF must be vector graphic if the input was. (Otherwise this could be easily achieved with `ImageMagick`).

I have a bunch of files which are just slightly larger / smaller than A4 and I want to rescale them so that they are within the A4 bounds before applying a stamp to them (which assumes a fixed page size): [Implementing a String -> PDF Stamp tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47727)

Comment: If you can roundtrip through PostScript, you can use `psresize`.

Comment: http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam looks promising.